# How do you deal with an "Error in eigen(a, symmetric = TRUE) : infinite or missing values in 'x'"?

Tags: r

I am running a smoothing spline regression to see changes in nest abundance over 32 years. I am using the ss function in r, and I have to admit I am pretty new at this. I have run several smoothing splines for other locations without any problem, but in this particular one, I keep getting the warning message "Warning message:

```
In sqrt(sse/(n - df)) : NaNs produced"
```

followed by the error message:

```
 "Error in eigen(a, symmetric = TRUE) : infinite or missing values in 'x'".
```

I have checked the data frame and it does not have missing values or infinite values but I can´t find the problem.
This is the code I am using:

```
plot(Tendencias$Año, Tendencias$Ei, col="black", xlab= "Year", ylab="Number of nests")
EiHolmodss<-with(Tendencias, ss(Año, Ei))
EiHolmodss
summary(EiHolmodss)
```

The data:

```
Tendencias$Año
 [1] 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006
[18] 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021
Tendencias$Ei
 [1]   67  156  111  160  151  400  403  309  548  710  527  333  210  272  333  402  602
[18]  409  730  595  316  583  608  722  729  505  533  740 1092 1045  765 1409
```

Tendencias$Año are the years where the number of nests was recorded, and Tendencias$Ei is the number of nests recorded each year.

Can someone please help me with tips to solve this problem?

Comment: you are specifying symmetry as True in your function but your data is not symmetric; as a matter of fact it is not even in square (matrix) form

Comment: @memo, how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the cause of your problem is that the length of the data equals the `df` so that `sqrt(sse/(n - df))` is undefined (expressed as `NaN`: not a number). In your case, the length of `Tendencias$Ei` is 32. If you don't specify `df` in `ss()` function, it will use 32 as the `df` value:

```
ano <- 1990:2021
ei <- c(67L, 156L, 111L, 160L, 151L, 400L, 403L, 309L, 548L, 710L, 
527L, 333L, 210L, 272L, 333L, 402L, 602L, 409L, 730L, 595L, 316L, 
583L, 608L, 722L, 729L, 505L, 533L, 740L, 1092L, 1045L, 765L, 
1409L)

model1 <- ss(ano,ei)

#Warning message:
#In sqrt(sse/(n - df)) : NaNs produced

model1

# Call:
#   ss(x = ano, y = ei)
# 
# Smoothing Parameter  spar = -1.496441   lambda = 9.202617e-19
# Equivalent Degrees of Freedom (Df) 32
# Penalized Criterion (RSS) -4.074536e-09
# Generalized Cross-Validation (GCV) -941509188153 

summary(model1)
# Error in eigen(a, symmetric = TRUE) : infinite or missing values in 'x'
```

To avoid this error, try to assign a value for `df` that differs from the length of the data. For example:

```
model2 <- ss(x = ano, y = ei, df = length(ei)-1)
summary(model2)

# Call:
#   ss(x = ano, y = ei, df = length(ei) - 1)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -10.6086  -2.8147   0.8173   2.5730   8.8342 
# 
# Approx. Signif. of Parametric Effects:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
# (Intercept)    505.7      4.433  114.07 0.005581 **
#   x             1337.6     34.969   38.25 0.016640  *
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
# 
# Approx. Signif. of Nonparametric Effects:
#   Df    Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
# s(x)      29 1011383.8 34875.3   56.81 0.1046  
# Residuals  1     613.9   613.9                 
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
# 
# Residual standard error: 24.78 on 1 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.9998,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9933
# F-statistic: 153 on 30 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.06391
```